# What is the difference between "His love burned" and "He was burned with love"?

Tags: phrases

What is the difference between "His love burned" and "He was burned with love"?

Which of them is the proper expression?

Comment: The passive *(He **was** burned with love)* is non-idiomatic. It's "just about" okay to say [*He was **burned up** with](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+was+burned+up+with%22) [some powerful emotion]*, but for ***love*** the most natural form is just [***He burned with love**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+burned+with+love%22) It's purely a stylistic choice whether to go for that or ***His love burned***.

Comment: Fumblefingers that would make a great basis for a formal answer

Comment: Seems more likely "burned" is being misused as "burning". If OP can clarify meaning as "was on fire with love" or similar then recommended action is edit to reflect this.

Comment: "He was burned with love" sounds like "He was gently cremated"!

Comment: There is insufficient detail to write a useful answer.  Please provide much more context

Answer (score 1):

*Burn* has a few different meanings.

*X burns* means X is acting like a fire and producing light/heat/energy/sustenance.  In the sentence *his love burns*, *love* is being figuratively used in the same sense as *fire*.

If X is a body part, it means X is experiencing a burning sensation, and this is typically not good.

> I touched the chemicals without gloves, and now my fingers burn.

If X is not on fire (concretely or figuratively) or causing pain, *burn* is not the right word to use.

> He was burned with love"

You might be thinking this could mean "He was caused to feel love" - nope.  You're making *love* sound like a chemical causing you physical pain here.

But using a progressive construct will turn *love* back into a passionate flame.

> He was burning with love

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score -2):

When it comes to romantic language like this generally more ornate language will be well received. In exhibitions of speech such as lectures more ornate speech may be common. This lies in the intersection between art and language. The audience determines how successful it is.